# Can I ask question about cleaning (not washing) my motorcycle?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to know some suggestions and methods for easy dust cleaning of motorcycle everyday. I mean the normal dust which comes on the motorcycle or any physical object when it is standing for 2-3 days.

I can't afford (and neither willing as my motorcycle is cheap one and entry level) some expensive things like blower or vacuum cleaner or any device that needs energy to operate.

Usually, people say there's a risk of scratch and swirls when you clean it with cloth (especially on glossy painted metal parts).

Also, I don't know easiest way to remove dust from joints (where two parts are joining so cloth won't reach there). Maybe a cheap brush can be used but I'm not sure what kind of brush I need.

I know some tools like microfiber cloth but I want to go into more details if there could be other similar suggestions and how to use them properly.

Answer (score 3):

To most people, cleaning is part of "maintenance". I'd suggest your question overall is completely within spec and on topic for the site.

Remember as you ask your question, we are not about recommending specific products, so it wouldn't be prudent to ask for those. Also, when asking your question, try to make sure your question is seeking specific advice which stays away from opinion. I'm sure there is a lot of opinion about how you (or anyone) should take care of their vehicles. Your question will have a much greater acceptance rate if you ensure your question remains as objective as possible.